# How can I use different type of thickness in an imported font?

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm making a website about my friend, and I imported the font called "roboto" from CDN fonts. But, after running the code, found it to be too thick, and not thinner like it was shown.

To wrap it up, Im just wondering how to make text more thin in the  part.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing font from https://www.cdnfonts.com/ you can use CSS to control thickness like so:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto Thin', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto Light', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto Medium', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto Black', sans-serif;
```

If you are using Google fonts add font-weight like shown on the screenshot and set the `font-weight` e.g. `font-weight: 300;` attribute to the desired element in your CSS.

[image]